# Configure default number format to 0 decimal places for new/existing workbooks in Excel 365 ProPlus?

Tags: excel

My problem is repeatedly removing decimal places throughout my workday.

Whenever I change a cell to number format, it defaults to 2 decimal places. 5 becomes 5.00. I then have to Decrease Decimal twice to convert the 5.00 back to 5.

I'm looking for a way to change Excel's settings so that the Number format option defaults to zero decimal places whenever I select Number format any time that I'm working with excel.

I tried the File >> Options >> Advanced menu, 2nd checkbox option to 0 decimal places and this does not work.  I am aware of the methods to manually change a cells formatting including number and custom formatting codes. But I do not know how to change the global setting to prevent the issue in the first place.

Is there a setting or configuation work around that would do this?

I'm using Excel 365 ProPlus Version 1708.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use styles.

- Right-click the Normal style, click Modify, click Format.
- Set the Number format to 0 decimals and confirm all dialogs.

Now all cells in your workbook that have been formatted with the Normal style (which is the default), will lose their decimals.

Do this with a new blank workbook and use it as a template for all new workbooks you start or put it in the Excel start folder.

Comment: This appears to change the formats of all Normal style cells to Number. This is a troublesome side effect that changes dates to number, text, etc.  The goal is to change the default decimal place in the event that a General or Text cell needs to be changed to Number.  Such as after pasting values, importing data stored as text, using other peoples' workbooks, using consistent formats for vlookups, etc.  Is there a way to change the 'background' Number format without changing the cell until Number format is activated?

Comment: Well, no, not really. A date is a number. An integer is a number, A decimal is a number. A time value is a number. When you enter or copy/paste any of these numbers, how is Excel going to figure out if you are pasting a date/time value, or a number that you don't want to display with decimals? With the style approach, you can default cells to the number format and then adjust to other formatting where you don't want that number format. If you don't want that, then go back to the default, where Excel decides what format to use. Which do you prefer?

Comment: That clarifies the problem well.  Preferably excel would continue to decide what format to use per usual with the rule that it NEVER chooses to display decimals. It seems that since it consistently applies 2 decimal places it could instead consistently apply 0 decimal places.  The lingering issue is that if I'm re-formatting time values to dates when before I was re-formatting decimals to no decimals, I'm still manually reformatting cells either way.  So the time savings are marginal if there's more decimals than dates or no savings at all if there's more dates to re-format now than decimals.

Comment: Excel currently does not offer the option to change the decimals for the default number format. You can suggest this as a new feature at [https://excel.uservoice.com/](https://excel.uservoice.com/), where people can vote for it. If it finds sufficient support from others, it may be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I have wasted a lot of time repeating the process of decreasing decimal places in Excel.

Natively Excel doesn't offer an option to change this.

The way you can tackle it is by doing it in Windows.

So for Windows 10:

1. Open Windows settings
2. Search for "Region"
3. Click additional date, time and regional settings
4. Click Format tab / Additional settings ...
5. Change the number of decimals

I have a [tutorial here](https://ricardodiaz.co/cantidad-de-decimales-al-aplicar-formato-a-celdas-en-excel/) (in spanish, but you get the picture)